# Is it possible to remove cURL command?

Tags: powershell, script, shell-script, active-directory, curl

I am a new Tier2, Tier3 is requesting I attempt to write a script to remove the curl command from student PC's, is this possible?  Should I suggest disabling curl via AD group policy?

Comment: You're new in the house. You should ask Tier 3 "What's the SOP for this kind of action?"

Comment: @John - Are you talking about the built-in Curl executable that has existed on every Windows installation since 2017? You should [edit] your question to include enough information to provide an accurate answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

When disabling access to tools like this, I generally find that AppLocker is the easiest solution. This should allow you to deploy a group policy that disables access to the curl executable.

You can read more about AppLock and how to get started using it here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-defender-application-control/applocker/applocker-overview

Comment: I would not advise the author to attempt to use AppLocker, with the built-in Curl capability, I have seen novice Administrator completely hose their system due to improper AppLocker configurations.

Comment: Yes, I agree, but a custom script to do it as recommended by the person above him has just as much danger. I hope they are testing any company-wide changes before deployment, but AppLocker is still the Microsoft-recommended tool for this problem space.

Comment: But you don't tell the author how to implement the AppLocker policy. If I knew, I would write an answer, so sadly, I am left providing feedback on somebody's answer.